# Node js Unit testing method where fields of a model are not selected by default

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, mongoose

Node js with mongoose.
model has fields that are not selected by default queries(`select:false` in model). In some scenarios I need to test the result to have the field selected. I have tried `sinon-mongoose` but it just tells me if a `populate` or `select` method was called, but for more flexibility I need to check the result data. And a requirement is not to use any real db connection, as it is a unit test.

The model

```
    var DoctorSchema = new Schema({
        firstName: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        lastName: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        middleName: {
            type: String
        },
        institutionName: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            select: false
        }
    });
```

The Service

```js
module.exports = function (Doctor) {
    service.getById = function(req, res, next){
        Doctor.findOne({"_id" : req.params.id}).select('+institutionName').exec(function (err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return
            };
            if (!doc) {
                res.send(404);
            }
            else {
                res.json(doc);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So this can be tested

```js
describe('doctorService getById', function () {
        it('presentationService should call getById', function (done) {
            var DoctorMock = sinon.mock(DoctorModel);
            DoctorMock
                .expects('findOne').withArgs({ "_id": "123" })
                .chain("select").withArgs('+institutionName')
                .chain('exec')
                .yields(null, seed.doctor);
            var serviceMock = doctorService(DoctorModel);
            var res = {
                json: function (data) {
                    DoctorMock.verify();
                    DoctorMock.restore();
                    assert.equal(seed.doctor, data, "Test fails due to unexpected result");
                    done();
                }
            };
            serviceMock.getById({param:{id:"123"}}, res);
        });
    });
```

But in my example the test is bound to the chain. My intuition tells me that this is not a good approach.

Comment: Could you please share some code with the specific problem so we could help?

Comment: thank you, I have updated the question